# What is the Problem with "fontspec" Package to Select Font Externally?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I want to use the `fontspec` package to select some fonts that I download from the internet for my document, but I constantly get this use error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ntspec_fontopts_clist ,,Path=\Users \BurakK \Downloads \Almond...
l.7 ...[Path=\Users\BurakK\Downloads\AlmondNougat]XeLaTeX compiler on TeXworks software.
```

when I try to compile this code with **XeLaTeX** on **TeXworks**,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AlmondNougat.ttf}[path=/Users/BurakK/Downloads/AlmondNougat]
\begin{document}
This is a test sentence to check font feature.
\end{document}
```

I tried many alternatives such as changing file name to a simpler, lowercase form, with .otf and .ttf file extensions, etc., but still to no avail. I even read the external font selection part from the package manual, but I have no idea as to what I do wrong here and how to solve this issue.

Edit:

In response to what is suggested in comment section, that is, with forward slash instead of backward slash in the file path, I get such an error this time:

```
Errors: 116, Warnings: 0, Bad boxes: 0


OT.mf
39
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

set_black_circle->...circle.scaled.line_thickness;

                                                  lft.x1=1/22size;y1=1/2size...

l.39 set_black_circle

OT.mf
39
Undefined x coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

set_black_circle->...size;y2=1/2size;filldraw.z1..

                                                  z2..cycle;black_circle:=cu...

l.39 set_black_circle

OT.mf
39
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

set_black_circle->...size;y2=1/2size;filldraw.z1..

                                                  z2..cycle;black_circle:=cu...

l.39 set_black_circle

OT.mf
39
Undefined x coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

set_black_circle->...;y2=1/2size;filldraw.z1..z2..

                                                  cycle;black_circle:=curren...

l.39 set_black_circle

OT.mf
39
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

set_black_circle->...;y2=1/2size;filldraw.z1..z2..

                                                  cycle;black_circle:=curren...

l.39 set_black_circle

OT.mf
47
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.47 beginchar(0,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
47
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.47 beginchar(0,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
47
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.47 beginchar(0,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
49
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.49   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
67
Undefined x coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.67   filldraw z5..

OT.mf
67
Undefined x coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.67   filldraw z5..z6..

OT.mf
79
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.79 beginchar(1,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
79
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.79 beginchar(1,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
79
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.79 beginchar(1,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
81
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.81   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
105
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.105 beginchar(2,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
105
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.105 beginchar(2,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
105
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.105 beginchar(2,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
107
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.107   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
119
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.119 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
133
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.133 beginchar(3,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
133
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.133 beginchar(3,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
133
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.133 beginchar(3,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
135
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.135   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
147
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.147 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
161
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.161 beginchar(4,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
161
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.161 beginchar(4,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
161
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.161 beginchar(4,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
163
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.163 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
175
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.175   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
189
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.189 beginchar(5,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
189
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.189 beginchar(5,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
189
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.189 beginchar(5,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
191
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.191 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
203
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.203   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
217
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.217 beginchar(6,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
217
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.217 beginchar(6,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
217
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.217 beginchar(6,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
219
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.219 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
233
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.233 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
239
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.239   draw z5..

OT.mf
239
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.239   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
251
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.251 beginchar(7,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
251
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.251 beginchar(7,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
251
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.251 beginchar(7,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
253
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.253 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
267
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.267 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
273
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.273   draw z5..

OT.mf
273
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.273   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
285
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.285 beginchar(8,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
285
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.285 beginchar(8,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
285
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.285 beginchar(8,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
287
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.287 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
301
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.301 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
307
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.307   draw z5..

OT.mf
307
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.307   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
319
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.319 beginchar(9,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
319
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.319 beginchar(9,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
319
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.319 beginchar(9,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
321
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.321 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
335
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.335 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
341
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.341   draw z5..

OT.mf
341
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.341   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
353
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.353 ...nchar(10,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
353
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.353 ...nchar(10,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
353
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.353 ...nchar(10,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
355
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.355   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
383
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.383 ...nchar(11,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
383
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.383 ...nchar(11,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
383
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.383 ...nchar(11,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
385
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.385   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
397
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.397 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
415
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.415 ...nchar(12,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
415
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.415 ...nchar(12,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
415
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.415 ...nchar(12,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
417
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.417   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
429
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.429 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
447
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.447 ...nchar(13,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
447
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.447 ...nchar(13,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
447
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.447 ...nchar(13,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
449
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.449 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
461
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.461   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
479
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.479 ...nchar(14,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
479
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.479 ...nchar(14,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
479
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.479 ...nchar(14,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
481
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.481 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
493
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.493   pickup pencircle scaled line_thickness;

OT.mf
511
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.511 ...nchar(15,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
511
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.511 ...nchar(15,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
511
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.511 ...nchar(15,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
513
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.513 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
527
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.527 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
533
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.533   draw z5..

OT.mf
533
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.533   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
549
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.549 ...nchar(16,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
549
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.549 ...nchar(16,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
549
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.549 ...nchar(16,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
551
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.551 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
565
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.565 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
571
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.571   draw z5..

OT.mf
571
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.571   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
587
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.587 ...nchar(17,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
587
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.587 ...nchar(17,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
587
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.587 ...nchar(17,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
589
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.589 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
603
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.603 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
609
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.609   draw z5..

OT.mf
609
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.609   draw z5..z6;

OT.mf
625
Internal quantity `charwd' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...byte(EXPR0)else:0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);

                                                  charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(E...

l.625 ...nchar(18,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
625
Internal quantity `charht' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...0fi;charwd:=(EXPR1);charht:=(EXPR2);

                                                  chardp:=(EXPR3);w:=hround(...

l.625 ...nchar(18,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
625
Internal quantity `chardp' must receive a known value.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

beginchar->...R1);charht:=(EXPR2);chardp:=(EXPR3);

                                                  w:=hround(charwd*hppp);h:=...

l.625 ...nchar(18,24/22size#,23/22size#,1/22size#)

OT.mf
627
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.627 ...p pencircle scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
641
Transform components aren't all known.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.641 ...up penrazor scaled border_line_thickness;

OT.mf
647
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ..

l.647   draw z5..

OT.mf
647
Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.

<to be read again> 

                   ;

l.647   draw z5..z6;

test.tex
7
Package fontspec Error: The font "abc" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...{abc.ttf}[path=/Users/BurakK/Downloads/abc]
```

Comment: Try putting your font file in the current directory, and make sure there's no space in the file name. Like so: \setmainfont{AlmondNougat.ttf}

If that works, it's probably a path issue.

Comment: Even on windows, the path is written with slashes (`/`): `\setmainfont{Almond Nougat}[path=/Users/BurakK/Downloads/AlmondNougat]`

Comment: It did not work out. @Ingmar

Comment: With what you have suggested I now get another error. @DG'

Comment: I am not a clairvoyant.

Comment: I appended new error message in the question. I forgot to inform you of I would do that earlier.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you seem to use a metafont source as fontspec font, that won't work. You need a ttf or otf font, and you don't get one by renaming an arbitrary file.

Comment: In that case I better look for more reliable font sources for fontspec package. Thank you, anyway. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Well it could also be that your font is simply not found. Try to use it by moving it to the current folder and without the Path setting.

Comment: I again got an error from using this alternative. @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AlmondNougat.otf}
\begin{document}
\LARGE This is a test sentence to check the font feature. It's nuts!
\end{document}
```

[image]

I downloaded the font from here: https://www.dafont.com/almond-nougat.font and renamed it AlmondNougat.otf (= removed the space from the file name) after putting it in the **current directory**, i.e. the one that also contains your .tex file.

Comment: That worked for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use the complete path or relative as `../myfont/NeoSt/` from your document.

In your case it might be

```
\setmainfont[%
Path=C:/Users//BurakK/Downloads/ ,
UprightFont = * ,
Extension = .ttf
]{AlmondNougat}
```

(Rename the file AlmondNougat.ttf without spaces in the name. Also note the need to use `Path` instead of `path` )

For the system fonts you need the real name of the file, using Properties, not what is shown in the main Font directory. The file name for italic is `timesi.ttf` and for bold face `timesbf.ttf`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont{AlmondNougat.ttf}[path=/Users/BurakK/Downloads/AlmondNougat]

\setmainfont[% OK7
Path = c:/windows/fonts/ ,
UprightFont = * ,
BoldFont = *bd ,
ItalicFont = *i ,
Extension = .ttf
]{times} % 


\begin{document}
    This is a \emph{test} sentence to \textbf{check} font feature.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using  Almond Nougat (a bold face font)

[image: almond]